# C# list of "Type" that implements specific interface

Tags: c#, interface, compile-time

I want to create a `List<System.Type> listOfTypesOfGlasses` , where `Type` must implement a specific interface `IGlass` , so I could load it with Types of glasses.
Is there a way to enforce in compile time this constraint(must implement `IGlass`) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement a method/class that hides the list.

```
class YourClass {
    // intentionally incomplete
    private List<Type> listOfTypesOfGlasses;
    public void AddToList<T>() : where T: IGlass
    {
        listOfTypesOfGlasses.Add(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Edit: below is the original answer here assuming that `Type` meant a placeholder, not `System.Type`.

<strike>All you should need to do is `List<IGlass>`.</strike>

*or*

You should write your own wrapper class around `List<T>` that has the constraint.

*or*

Subclass `List<T>` and put the generic constraint on it - however this practice is discouraged.

Comment: for the first idea - no -as this will create list that contains instances of classes that implements `IGlass`.
I want not instances of classes, but instances of class `Type` , that i know that the data contained describes a type that implements `IGlass`.
 The second and third ideas - I am not sure how can I do it or how it helps me

Comment: is there a way of doing this for arrays?
Basically I want to this to initialize an attribute(new to C#, just figured out that attributes can only be initialized with arrays)

Comment: @YoavR. you can't have it both ways - an attribute declaration has to be completely compile time and they don't work with generics. which attribute are you using? perhaps there is some lazy logic you can use with it.

Comment: @daniel-a-white -I am implementing a Bar class - which is a base class for regular bar, dance bar, etc. and I want to declare an attribute that will organize the types of glasses used in the bar

Comment: @YoavR. that sounds like a completely different question. there might be a better way to do what you want besides using attributes.

Comment: @Daniel-A-White - this data is known at compile time - it sounds like the best way to do that

Comment: @YoavR. perhaps the best/easiest solution is to use an enum for each type.

Answer (score 1):

No - `typeof(IGlass)` and `typeof(Glass)` are both `Type` objects - not different classes that can be filtered in a generic constraint.  There's no generic restriction that works off of the *values* stored. If you want to store *instances* of types that all implement `IGlass` that's possible, but you can't filter the actual `Type` objects that can be stored.